# Is it possible to disable App Nap for a single thread?

Tags: c++, objective-c, osx-mavericks

Is it possible to disable OS/X Mavericks' "App Nap" feature for just a specific thread in a process?  If so, how can that be done?  (A C or C++-based approach would be ideal, but an Objective-C one would work too)

(Background explanation:  I have a C++ app where I don't mind if the GUI "naps", but it has a network-heartbeat thread that I'd like to make sure remains performant at all times, since otherwise other devices on the network will notice it not responding in a timely manner and can be unhappy with it)

Comment: As I understand it, the app is only frozen if it's not performing background work. If you have a socket associated with your run loop, that will constitute "work" and keep your app alive.

Comment: @RichardHodges Is that true even if the run loop is pthread/select() based rather than an NSRunLoop ?

Comment: I don't know. you'll need to test it. apple's developer documentation is legendarily awful.

Comment: From what I've seen, the thread does occasionally stop responding for a short amount of time.  It's not clear to me whether that's due to App Nap or for some other reason though.